# AWSSDK linux AMI look up

Tags: c#

I've used the AWSSDK for .net as below in c#:

```
var img_desc= Amazon.EC2.Util.ImageUtilities.WINDOWS_2008_BASE;
string imageId = ImageUtilities.FindImage(ec2Client, img_desc).ImageId;
```

which allows me to map image name to the ami id.
But for some strange reason, they only have done it for windows and not for linux.
Is there a similar way (api or publicly shared map) that I can look up ami id from linux distro like this?

```
string ami_id = ???.findImage("Ubuntu10.4");
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
        var filter1 = new Filter("description", new List<string> { "*SUSE*" });
        var req = new DescribeImagesRequest();
        req.Filters.Add(filter1);
        req.Owners.Add("amazon");
        var imgs = ec2Client.DescribeImages(req);
        foreach(Amazon.EC2.Model.Image img in imgs.Images)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(img.Name + " , " + img.ImageId + " , " + img.Description + " , " + img.Platform + " , " + img.Architecture);
        }
```

Note that you must use a filter otherwise you'll have to wait for 33000 images to load.
Also note that many images do not have the platform property set and therefore you'll have to search within the name and description.